# WSL : Function not implemented

Tags: c, system, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I know that wsl uses translates every command to be executed from the Windows kernel, but still, my question is : 
**Does WSL support system calls (e.g. message queues) and if yes,how?**

I am getting the "Function not implemented" error whenever using any of the message queue functions.Is there any hope at all?

[EDIT:]

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){ 
    key_t key=MSG_KEY;
    mqid=msgget(key,0660 | IPC_CREAT );
    if(mqid==-1){
        perror("msgget error:");
        printf(" %s",strerror(errno));
    }
    int lenght=0,n=0;
    lenght=msgrcv(mqid,&req,MAX,1,0);
    if(lenght==-1){      
        if (errno == ENOMSG)
        {
            printf("\nNo message in the queue\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nError receiving message: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Received a message\n");
    }
    printf("\nreceived %d number of bytes\n",n);
    msgctl(mqid,IPC_RMID,NULL); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us a piece of code that's not working. WSL is actually using a virtual machine, so it should support all functions of linux.

Comment: @PMF , just posted the code

Comment: Have you added the required header file for `msgctl`?

Comment: The first sentence about the translation of Linux system calls to Windows NT system calls is only true for WSL 1. WSL 2 includes its own Linux kernel running in parallel with the Windows NT kernel.

Comment: Does your version of Windows support WSL 2? If so, it is possible to convert existing WSL 1 distros to WSL 2, which should solve the problem.

Comment: @Linux Geek yes, <sys/types.h><sys/ipc.h><sys/msg.h> are included in this file.

Answer (score 5):

System V IPC is missing in WSL(1), which is what msgctl belongs to.

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1016